# Where can i get SpringSource Tool 2.60 for linux

Tags: spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I know STS 3.60 is available now a days but seems like i need STS version 2.60 for Linux(Ubuntu to be specific). Can any one tell me where i can get it.

(I need it as it seem, projects created in 3.60 are not compatible in 2.60, and colleagues use 2.6 in windows)

So can any one please provide me where i can download STS v 2.6

Thank You in advance

Comment: Before somebody vote to close (because tit is obvious, or just use google), just try it yourself! - http://spring.io/tools/sts/all - contains only the newest version, but not the older once (or I did not find it too).

Comment: The correct name in the Headline is supposed to be "Spring Tool Suite" - and the version is 3.6.0 and maybe 2.something, but I am sure there was never a x.60 - I strongly recommend to correct it so that your question become a bit more correct.

Comment: @Ralph The OP probably does mean 2.6.0, and at the time the name was "SpringSource Tool Suite".

Comment: @chrylis: you are right: anyway "SpringSource Tool" and "2.60" is wrong. A OP should show that he has at lease a minimal understanding, and that he takes care about what he ask.

Answer (score 1):

The SpringSource Tool Suite 2.6.0 was based on Eclipse 3.6 and the workspaces of Eclipse 4.4 and 3.6 are indeed not compatible to each other anymore.

STS 2.6.0 for Linux is available from here:
http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/2.6.0.SR1/dist/e3.6/springsource-tool-suite-2.6.0.SR1-e3.6.2-linux-gtk.tar.gz

http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/2.6.0.SR1/dist/e3.6/springsource-tool-suite-2.6.0.SR1-e3.6.2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

Comment: is there a page that contains all the old versions

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that the Problem is STS by it self. I think that the problem is the underlying Eclipse Version. So I recommend that you check on which Eclipse your colleagues STS is based (Eclipse 4.x or 3.x) and then download

Eclipse in the right version from:

http://spring.io/tools/eclipse

and then: install the STS Plugins via update by the Urls provided at:

https://spring.io/tools/sts/all

*(Sometimes it takes a minute until this site is complete loaded!)*