# Where can I find previous versions of STS spring

Tags: spring, archive

I have been tasked with fixing a bug found in a legacy app written in version 2.4.0 or 2.6.0 of STS.

After spending the better part of 2 days trying to port it to 3.6.2 without success I need to get my hands on either of these older releases to see if this even works or if there is something wrong with the app code base.  I have spent the better part of an hour searching STS Spring for previous versions but can't find anything on the site.  Where are previous versions of STS or why have they been stashed away?

OS Target: Window 7 - 64 bit

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I download older versions of STS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567877/how-can-i-download-older-versions-of-sts)

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602841/where-can-i-get-springsource-tool-2-60-for-linux) post and the filename of the [current version](http://spring.io/tools/sts/all/), you come up with: http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/2.6.0.SR1/dist/e3.6/springsource-tool-suite-2.6.0.SR1-e3.6.2-win32-x86_64.zip

Very strange that they are not linking the old versions even though they are still available.